# Cannot get random color generator in Kotlin to work

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, random, colors, hex

Trying to generate a random color hexadecimal...Here's my code so far

```kotlin
import android.graphics.Color
import kotlin.random.Random
import kotlin.random.nextInt

fun main(){
    val rnd = Random.Default //kotlin.random
    val color = Color.argb(255, rnd.nextInt(256), rnd.nextInt(256), rnd.nextInt(256))
    }
```

This is the error I'm getting

```kotlin
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Stub!
    at android.graphics.Color.argb(Color.java:137)
    at com.example.functionexample.FunctionExampleKt.main(FunctionExample.kt:12)
    at com.example.functionexample.FunctionExampleKt.main(FunctionExample.kt)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Tried searching for this error online but can't find anything. Theres no error messages on my actual code but when I run it I get that

Comment: You can't use android libs like `android.graphics.Color` in projects running on non-android device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like *bylazy* says in the comments, you can't use Android libraries outside of an Android device like that. You're getting the *"Stub!"* error because the library you have downloaded doesn't have any code in its methods, except to throw an exception with that message. They're just placeholders - but when you run it on a device/emulator, the full library will be available there with actual method implementations.

If you just need to create a hex string, you can call `toString(16)` on your random numbers to get the individual hex parts. You could create a function like this:

```
fun getRandomHex() = Random.nextInt(255).toString(16).uppercase()

println("FF${getRandomHex()}${getRandomHex()}${getRandomHex()}")
```

Or maybe use a property

```
val rndHex get() = Random.nextInt(255).toString(16).uppercase()

println("FF$rndHex$rndHex$rndHex")
```

Comment: So what I am doing with this project is that I am making an AIDL between two android apps on Android studios. Where I am implementing the color changing function is in my aidlserver, from which I am going to download the apk onto my Pixel 2 android emulator. Do you think it will work in that case? The whole time I have been using android studio I was just testing that function in a no activity kotlin file to see if it works. There is a video on youtube where a guy makes an the same color changing aidl but he does it in java where I am doing it in kotlin. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Just to clarify, my aidl server was created with no activity and the functionality for this function resides in my Service file (Where the binder is). I am going to download this apk to my emulator and then run my client

Comment: @AlexJordan I don't know anything about AIDL, but the Android "environment" only exists on an actual device (or emulator). So if you just run a Kotlin script on your computer, `Color#argb` exists but it's a stub method - an empty one, just something for you to write and compile code against. But that code will work fine on an Android device/emulator. It's nothing to do with Java or Kotlin, it's just where the code is running. It's the same reason that when you're writing tests, anything that calls the Android framework needs to run on a device (instrumented test) or be mocked etc

Comment: So yeah, your code up there will run fine on the Android OS itself, and it doesn't matter if it's in an Activity or whatever - it's just a function call to a static framework method. But outside of Android, you just have a skeleton framework with stub methods that just throw exceptions, so you can't run code that interacts with that stuff specifically there. Libraries you import as dependencies etc - that's all fine, because you actually have the real code for those. Standard `android` library stuff though - device/emulator only (and some methods only exist on certain API versions of course!)

Comment: Ok this makes sense. I am an ECE major in a software engineering internship right now so I had to learn kotlin and android studios, while at the same time not having the best coding experience. I really appreciate the help tho, trying to learn this is confusing but I'm happy to have people like you give me good advice and hopefully this helps others too. Thank you!

Comment: @AlexJordan yeah this isn't really a coding thing, more an Android-specific thing. You don't have a real copy of the Android framework in your development environment, so you can't run code in your IDE, in scripts etc that try to use the framework APIs. Usually this doesn't matter - normally you build an app and run it on a real or virtual Android device, where (a version of) the framework exists. But for things like tests, you want to be able to compile and run your Kotlin code on the computer because it's quicker than running it through Android.

Comment: Framework calls prevent that, because they don't exist (well, don't work) on the host machine, so you can't run that code correctly. So you'll typically see tests split up into *local* and *instrumented* ones - local for the Android-agnostic code that will run fine, and instrumented for stuff that has to interact with the framework, so needs to be run on a device/emulator. There's more to it than that, but that's the basic problem! And it's a similar situation for your script. The start of this describes what's happening: https://developer.android.com/training/testing/local-tests Good luck!